# c# generating a crc8 byte method with a byte array input

Tags: c#, crc

Right now I have the following code to generate a CRC-16 (Modbus). I am rather new to the idea of CRC, and I need to make a CRC-8. Can this code be modified to generated a CRC-8? I have the for loop starting at `int = 1;` and ending at `i<tembByteList.Count - 1;` because I am ignoring the first and last byte.

```
public List<byte> crc16(List<byte> tempByteList)
    {
        ushort reg_crc = 0xFFFF;
        for(int i = 1; i<tempByteList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            reg_crc ^= tempByteList[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if((reg_crc & 0x01) == 1)
                {
                    reg_crc = (ushort)((reg_crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
                }
                else
                {
                    reg_crc = (ushort)(reg_crc >> 1);
                }
            }
        }
        tempByteList.Insert(tempByteList.Count - 1, (byte)((reg_crc >> 8) & 0xFF));
        tempByteList.Insert(tempByteList.Count - 1, (byte)(reg_crc & 0xFF));
        return tempByteList;
    }
```

Comment: It's somewhat odd to return a `List<byte>` for a CRC at all. Any reason you're not returning a `ushort` for a CRC-16 and a `byte` for a CRC-8?

Comment: (It's odd to modify the input, too. It would be much more common to just write a method to compute the checksum without modifying anything - let the caller insert the checksum at the start of the list/array/whatever if they want to.)

Comment: [Here's someone's C# implementation of a CRC8](https://blog.csdn.net/plutus_sutulp/article/details/8473377)

Comment: My code generates a byte array of variable length based off of some user inputs. I use a list because I can just add bytes depending on those inputs. Then the last operation I want to do is add the checksum byte(s) right before the end byte. So I just decided to do it this way. That can be changed though. I see what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just replace `0xa001` with `0xe5`, and the initialization with zero (`ushort reg_crc = 0;`). That will generate the Bluetooth CRC-8. Using `0x8c` will generate the Maxim CRC-8. And of course you'll only need to insert one byte into your message at the end.

If you would prefer a CRC that initializes with all ones, which would be sensitive to an initial string of zeros in the message, then you can use the ROHC CRC-8, which would use `0xe0` for the polynomial, and you would initialize `reg_crc` to `0xff`.

By the way, the `if` statement could be replaced by a a ternary operator, which I consider to be more readable:

```
    reg_crc = (reg_crc & 1) != 0 ? (reg_crc >> 1) ^ POLY : reg_crc >> 1;
```

Comment: would I insert the byte with or without the bit shift?

Comment: It's just the low byte, so no shift.

Comment: @user9964422 I just noticed an initialization that needs to be changed as well. Answer updated.

Comment: I also need to implement a similar function in c++. A language I am much less familiar with. for the statement you're using to replace the if statement would the operators be the same?

Comment: Yes. Though if you like, you could leave out the `!= 0` for C++. So `reg_crc & 1 ? ...`.